# How to recolor Windows Form's title bar C#

Tags: c#, colors, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-forms-designer

I want recolor only the windows form's title bar of my application, I found this code online

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
     const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;
     base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_NCPAINT)
        {

            IntPtr hdc = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
            if ((int)hdc != 0)
            {
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc);
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 10, 0, 4800, 23);
                g.Flush();
                ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, hdc);
            }

        }
    }
```

But I don't know how to trigger it, Could you help me?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe: _"In Windows Vista and later, the appearance of the non-client areas of application windows (the title bar, icon, window border, and caption buttons) is controlled by the DWM. Using the DWM APIs, you can change the way the DWM renders a window's frame."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to set the FormBorderStyle property to None, then I used a flowLayoutPanel to used as as my title bar,setting mouse events and addinng minimize/close button.